# Compiling ffmpeg for mingw leads to undefined reference?

Tags: c++, windows, ffmpeg, mingw

I would like to use `ffmpeg` for windows and `mingw` which made me look at:

- https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MinGW
- https://dev.to/codesomething/installing-mingw-w64-on-windows-and-fixing-the-weird-file-downloaded-incorrectly-error-4b85

I was successful at using `MSYS` according to the documentation / guides above. I followed these steps:

1. Download ffmpeg source files ([from here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/)).
2. Open `MSYS mingw shell`
3. Go to the ffmpeg directory.
4. Run `./configure --disable-shared --enable-static`
5. Run `make -j4`
6. Run `make install`

But when I am trying to compile `g++ -o main main.cpp -IC:\ffmpeg\include -LC:\ffmpeg\lib -lavformat`:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
    #include "libavformat/avformat.h"
    #include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
    #include "libswscale/swscale.h"
}

int main() {
    avformat_network_init();
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error message: `undefined reference to 'avformat_network_init'` which I assume is me doing something incorrectly when installing the libraries since if I change the `-lavformat` to something else I get `cannot find -lSOMETHING`. The headers are also "found" since I can use for example `AVFormatContext* formatContext = NULL;` found in `avformat.h`. The lib directory contains: `libavcodec.a libavdevice.a libavfilter.a libavformat.a libavutil.a libswresample.a libswscale.a`

Am I missing something obvious or where could the issue be?

Comment: You don't need to compile it by hand, and there's barely any reason to use the old MSYS1. Get [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075) and install ffmpeg as a prebuilt package.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it does indeed work to install & compile via MSYS2 but I already have a complete installation of mingw on my computer. Can I just move the include and lib folders from the MSYS2 version and make it work that way? (Sorry I am fairly new to these kind of things)

Comment: Just no. It could give you some hard to debug issues. MSYS2 is one of the few sane MinGW distributions out there (one of the few that ships an up-to-date compiler, and I believe the only one with a package manager). I would uninstall any existing versions of MinGW you have.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat this does indeed work as a "workaround" I suppose? I have followed your advice and will be working with the MSYS2 version of mingw in the future. But I leave the question as it is because I feel like the ffmpeg windows documentation is rather lacking (unless I missed something).

Comment: Since MSYS2 is open-source, you can look at the steps they do to build it, here: https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/tree/master/mingw-w64-ffmpeg